# GXT3/GWT - How to remove cells(HasCell) from compositeCell dynamically?

Tags: gwt, gxt, treegrid, datagridcell

I have a list of cells which i'll send it as an argument to create a composite cell. In the below code i'm creating the cells and adding it to the list.

```
List<HasCell<SensorTreeModel, ?>> cells= new ArrayList<HasCell<SensorTreeModel,?>>();
      com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell editSwitchIcon = new com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell(ButtonType.EDITSWITCH);
      com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell editIcon = new com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell(ButtonType.EDIT);
      com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell switchRoleIcon = new com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell(ButtonType.SWITCH);
      com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell breakIcon = new com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell(ButtonType.BREAK);
      com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell deleteIcon = new com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell(ButtonType.DELETE);
      cells.add(editSwitchIcon);
      cells.add(editIcon);
      cells.add(switchRoleIcon);
      cells.add(breakIcon);
      cells.add(deleteIcon);
```

In the below code. I'm adding the list to the composite cell.(ActionCell)

```
actionsCol.setCell(new ActionCell(cells));
```

Now what if I want to delete the cells dynamically in the columnConfig(actionCell) depending on the object which is going into the column?

Comment: Are you trying to change which cell you render per-row, or rebuild the entire column at once and redraw all cells?

Comment: @ColinAlworth I am trying to change the cell I render per-row.

Comment: @ColinAlworth Is there any possible way to print each image in a new line?